# How can i control users from accessing files

Tags: file-sharing

How can I control access to files although the user has read/write access to the records?  Ex scenario: User A & B have r/w access to a record X. User A wants to attach a file to record X, but do not want the User B to see/access the file. is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Is this in Lightning?

Comment: We are now in classic.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Make a File Private](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_make_private.htm&type=5)

Comment: I looked, but it did not help.

Comment: Well I don't know if you could do this in Classic, but there's an [option in Lightning](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_make_private_on_record.htm&type=5).

Comment: Thanks Jayant. It is helpful. Solution would be... make the file private by checking the checkbox 'File Privacy on Records' on File, then explicitly share with users.